# English use of finds or will find

Tags: word-choice

Which is best to use:

> 1. He hopes he **finds** the answer for the test before the next quiz.
>      or
> 2. He hopes he **will find** the answer for the test before the next quiz.

Comment: They're both fine - it's purely a stylistic choice with no significant semantic implications.

Answer (score 1):

He hopes:

... (that) he lives to see personal jetpacks become commonplace.

... to live to see personal jetpacks become commonplace.

... (that) he will live to see personal jetpacks become commonplace.

.... (that) he might live to see personal jetpacks become commonplace.